# Matlab `imagesc`: how to display with smooth colors?

Tags: image, matlab, figure, matlab-figure

I have a matrix which I display with `imagesc`. Now I'm asked to make an "interpolated" version (i.e. display with smoother colors).

While I could compute a larger interpolated matrix, I seem to remember that there was a command to switch between two such display modes, either a little command in the style of `axis equal` or some Property - but I just cannot find it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may want to use [`pcolor`](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/pcolor.html) instead of `imagesc` and set the [`shading`](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/shading.html) properties to `interp`.

Note that [`pcolor`](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/pcolor.html) and `imagesc` will not display your data in the same way but the [`shading`](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/shading.html) property is only available for faceted plots.

However this is only a display solution, you will have to interpolate your data if you want to work with it afterwards.

Comment: Thanks Aabaz, yes, that does the trick - I don't remember `pcolor` at all but `shading interp` sounds familiar. And yes, I was looking explicitly for a solution that affects the display only. It is a bit annoying, though, that the last row & column isn't displayed at all with `shading flat` (on the first glance `pcolor` looks _very_ different from `imagesc`).

Comment: Just to give an example of how pcolor and imagesc don't display the data in the same way: imagesc is a 2d figure, while pcolor returns a 3d figure. The latter is undesired if your z-data is larger than zero, because your plot will obscure the axes!